# Applying jQuery Mobile attributes to XPages controls

Tags: jquery-mobile, xpages

I have just started looking into using jQuery Mobile on a XPages project. I am unsure whether I should use XPages controls or standard HTML controls in certain circumstances.

For example, I need a simple "Save" button on a page. An xp:button does get rendered with the jQuery Mobile style. But how would I then apply attributes to it, such "data-icon" and "data-inline"?

Or should I be using a standard HTML  tag in this case? If so, I lose the ability to code XPages simple actions to, say, save the data sources.

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using 8.5.3 you can use the attr property of the button to add the data-icon and data-inline tags.

```
<xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
    <xp:this.attrs>
        <xp:attr name="data-icon" value="marky"></xp:attr>
    </xp:this.attrs>
</xp:button>
```

If not then you can use jQuery to add the attribute using $().attr('data-icon', 'whatever'). Remember though the clientID of the button will change through the interface and you will need to adjust for that. You could you my x$ function
http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=x-jquery-selector-for-xpages

Comment: Using 8.5.3, so the attr property did the job. Thanks.